SQLite Strict Mode or any other alternatives
I am currently developing a QT C++ Application for my friend's shop. Simple application for inventory management and billing system. So, the DB will be in his computer itself which also hosts the application. There is only one system.
So for DB I thought, I needed something light weight and I concluded I'll be using SQLite instead of MySQL which I use professionally.
Only today I found out that SQLite doesn't enforce type which was a bummer. That can be enabled either by writing constraints or during time of creation (CREATE query), I should append the word "STRICT" at the end.
Note: I use DB Browser to view my SQLite DB.
So, my question is,

Is there any way to enable STRICT by default? Or ALTER the already created tables to add STRICT?
If not, what are the alternatives? I thought of MySQL and PostGreSQL. I prefer something light weight as in takes up the least amount of space for storage. Open for suggestions.
Despite this feature, should I stick with SQLite for my requirement in your opinion?

I would appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.

Simple very rarely stays that way. In that vein SQLite is an embedded database that does not really understand  users or concurrent connections. My guess is at some point you will need those features and will end up moving to client/server database.

"enforce type" -- What are you referring to?  There are several ways that MySQL bites users over type inconsistencies -- JOIN, WHERE, etc.

@RickJames. SQLite quirks: 3. Flexible Typing.

I would be curious to hear how much bulkier MySQL is than SQLite.
